# SQL Compact Problem After Installing on Vista Client

Tags: windows-vista, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run an application that normally works when I install on XP, but it doesn't work when I install it on Vista.  I am installing the prerequisite of .NET 3.5 SP1 and SQL Compact 3.5 included as part of the install but I still get this exception:

Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling both, and then re-installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Vista 32- or 64-bit?  Since CE CE's engine is native, there are separate binaries for each and you have to ensure you're using the correct ones.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  It is working on the 32-bit, but not the 64-bit machine.  That could be the issue.  How can I have my installer install the correct SQL CE Bits?  Should I have two installers?  If so, where do I get the 64-bit SQL CE?

Comment: Take a look at Steve Lasker's blog entry here: http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx. He covers how to deply 32 and 64-bit and where they get installed by default on your PC